# Odd number in anonymous hash

Tags: perl

Anyone can explain me why this warning occurs in my program. So far my limited knowledge of `perl`, this should work properly.

```
$clone = $cromozom;
print "-- Clone: $clone->{_secventa} | $clone->{_performanta} \n";
mutatie($clone);
print "-- After mutation: $clone->{_secventa} | $clone->{_performanta} \n";
$clone->{_performanta} = performanta{$clone->{_secventa}};
$counter += 1;
```

And this is the `performanta` subroutine.

```
sub performanta{
    my $sir = shift;
    my $distanta = 0;
    my $index;

    for($index = 0; $index < length($sir); $index +=1){
        $distanta += abs(ord(substr($sir, $index, 1)) - ord(substr($solutieOptima, $index, 1)));
    }

   return $distanta;
```

}

It says `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash` at this line: `$clone->{_performanta} = performanta{$clone->{_secventa}};`.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're used to Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `performanta{$clone->{_secventa}}`.  When perl tries to parse this, it's getting `performanta( { $clone->{_secventa} } )` which is:

- call the performanta sub
- it gets one parameter
- that one parameter is an anonymous hash ref, initialised with `{ ... }`
- the list that initialises that hash ref is only one item long, `$clone->{_secventa}`.

It's not entirely clear to me what you intended, but it's entirely clear to perl that whatever you told it isn't going to be what you intended to tell it, thus the helpful warning.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I figured it out eventually.